# Brownian motion independent from a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, solution-verification, independence

I was looking at [theorem 22.1 here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~pitman/s205s03/b_bridge.pdf)
, where one wants to show that a **Brownian bridge** $(\tilde B_t)_t$ is **independent** from the random variable $B(1)$. This seems a bit tricky to me: one is a process, the other one is a random variable.

What is done in the proof is just to take a partition $t_1 \leq \ldots \leq t_n$ and compute the covariance between $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \tilde B(t_i) \text{ and } B(1)$$

They see that the covariance is $0$ and hence they conclude that they're independent. Is it because $(\tilde B(t_1), \ldots , \tilde B(t_n))$ and $B(1)$ are jointly Gaussian?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: @Canardini thanks for the feedback. BY the way, they're jointly Gaussian since I can write the vector $(\tilde B(t_1), \ldots, \tilde B(t_n),B(1))$ as a matrix times the vector $(B(t_1), \ldots, B(t_n),B(1))$, which should be Gaussian I think. But I have in the last component $B(1)$ and this puzzles me a bit...why is it Gaussian?